# flutter update value of variable inside ChangeNotifier

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a `notifier.dart` file where I have declared some `ChangeNotifiers`. One of which is `OpacityChangeNotifier`.

OpacityChangeNotifier Class:

```
class OpacityChangeNotifier extends ChangeNotifier {
  double _opacity = 1.0;
  double get opacity => _opacity;

  void changeOpacity(double providedOpacity) {
    _opacity = providedOpacity;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void printOpacity() {
    print(_opacity);
  }
}
```

This is for my coloring app where I want the user to start with an opacity of `1.0`. Then he/she can change it.

Here's the `opacity_picker` widget

```
final _opacityProvider = ChangeNotifierProvider<OpacityChangeNotifier>((ref) {
  return OpacityChangeNotifier();
});

class OpacityPicker extends ConsumerWidget {
  const OpacityPicker({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, ScopedReader watch) {
    final opacityPicker = watch(_opacityProvider);
    return Container(
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
        children: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
            onPressed: () {
              opacityPicker.changeOpacity(0.1);
            },
            icon: Icon(Icons.opacity, size: 20),
          ),
          IconButton(
            onPressed: () {
              opacityPicker.changeOpacity(0.5);
            },
            icon: Icon(Icons.opacity, size: 20),
          ),
          IconButton(
            onPressed: () {
              opacityPicker.changeOpacity(1.0);
            },
            icon: Icon(Icons.opacity, size: 20),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Now I want to use this opacity_picker inside another widget called `menu_items`. I've added a simple Icon button to test if the values(0.1,0.5,1.0) for opacity were getting updated or not.

```
IconButton(
  onPressed: () {
     opacity.printOpacity();
  },
  icon: Icon(Icons.dock_rounded),
)
```

But it seems the value is remaining the same which I provided as default: `1.0`. Any solution on how to update the value I provided or any other way how I can change the opacity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with how you're instantiating `ChangeNotifierProvider` just above your `OpacityPicker` class.  So I'm not sure if that's correct or not.

As `Provider` is built with `InheritedWidget`, any part of your app you wish to be "reactive" to changes of `Provider` state, needs to be a child underneath your `ChangeNotifierProvider`.

One way to ensure this is to wrap `MyApp` with your `ChangeNotifierProvider`.  Therefore, your entire app is within the Provider's InheritedWidget scope.  Remi (author of Provider) shows this in [his example code](https://pub.dev/packages/provider/example):

```
void main() {
  runApp(
    /// Providers are above [MyApp] instead of inside it, so that tests
    /// can use [MyApp] while mocking the providers
    MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => Counter()),
      ],
      child: const MyApp(),
    ),
  );
}
```

He's using `MultiProvider` but you can see that `MyApp()` is the child of `Provider`.

Are you doing something similar in your app?